# Passing Django variables to forms in templates

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm building a website and I'm trying to make the user able to change his credentials. I've made a form for this:

```py
newUsername = forms.CharField(
    label="Enter your new username here*",
    required=True,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'class': 'userChangeCredentials',
    'value': "{{ user.username }}"
}))
newEmail = forms.EmailField(
    label="Enter your new e-mail adress here*",
    required=True,
    widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
    'class': 'userChangeCredentials',
    'value': '{{ user.email }}'
}))
newPassword = forms.CharField(
    label="Enter your new password here",
    required=False,
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
    'class': 'userChangeCredentials',
    'value': ''
}))
passwordConfirmation = forms.CharField(
    label="Confirm your existing password here*",
    required=True,
    max_length=256,    
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
    'class': 'userChangeCredentials',
    'value': ''
}))
```

The problem is, that the values in the widget dictionary are passed as raw text and I want them to be variables.

This is the resulting page layout:

[image: The output]

Do I need to change something inside of HTML?

My HTML:

```html
<form id="UserForm" action="{% url 'user' name=user.username %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|safe }}
    <input class="userChangeCredentials" type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

I tried to make the text raw like this:

```py
widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
    'class': 'userChangeCredentials',
    'value': r'{{ user.email }}'
})
```

But it didn't help. I searched for a week and I couldn't find any questions of this nature. I've read the official [Django form page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/), but there is nothing about this exact thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I suggest you use the form for the user credentials only (email and username), then use the built-in `PasswordChangeView` for updating the user password without even creating a form class for it.

As for the raw values, the best way to get them is to inherit the form from the User model.

Comment: No, I'm not, it's probably better, but i created completely new form, the full class line is here:
` class UserCredentialsForm(forms.Form): `
thank you, but I can't use this idea since I'm creating completely new form...

Comment: Would you like me to write you the code for the above explanation, or is it not fitting to your problem?

Comment: I recreated the original form to the model, but i still don't know, how to pass the value into it. If you can recreate it to the code it will help me a lot, thank you.

Comment: No need anymore! I've got my answer here, just simple instance arg in place, where i am rendering the form. Oh my god. Anyway thank you a lot. https://dev.to/earthcomfy/django-update-user-profile-33ho